# Why Athorized.net for Android is not working and I am not getting device status ?

Tags: android, authorize.net

I am developing an App having Authorized.net Api but unable to login,even I am not getting option of enabling a device.

Comment: https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/.Same as given in link

Comment: The same code worked for me properly. Check each steps once again. Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I am not able to login.Only getting logs getMerchant().

Comment: Try with one fresh application once again. You must be missing some step. That tutorial works properly.

Comment: Is your error solved now ?

Comment: I am able to login.Thanks.But giving error after login "Transaction of this market type cannot be processed on this system".Why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49626/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-swati)

Comment: @Swati : i am also stuck in the same time of problem.can you share your sample project with me?

Comment: @biginner Make a fresh project.It will work definitely.else share your mail id

Comment: @Swati : can u send me your sample project and library u used on romil_modi@yahoo.com

Comment: @Swati : actually i have tried 3 to four times but facing same problem again and again :/

Comment: @Swati : not got your mail yet..have you sent it?